# Global.asax's Application_Start method doesn't get called

Tags: wcf, ninject, automapper, global-asax

I have a WCF web service hosted on my Local IIS (not Express). I've included a Global.asax in its root directory, where it is supposed to be. Since I'm using Ninject with WCF extensions, the class Global extends NinjectHttpApplication instead of HttpApplication (as seen [here](http://gigi.nullneuron.net/gigilabs/dependency-injection-in-wcf-services-with-ninject/)).
Also, I'm using the AutoMapper library in order to circumvent writing boring boilerplate code.
The problem arises because a static method I defined for configuring AutoMapper isn't being called causing AutoMapper to throw exceptions when I call Mapper.Map(). That static method's call is defined in Global.asax's Application_Start() method since I want these mappings to be performed once per the web service's lifetime.
Ninject's CreateKernel() method gets called just fine, by the way.
Am I missing something here? I've tried debugging it, it doesn't hit the breakpoint even though I've attached the debugger to w3wp.exe and also tried putting an explicit Debugger.Break() call in its body.

This is how it looks like so far:

Global.asax

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="MyApp.WebHost.Global" Language="C#" %>
```

Global.asax.cs

```
public class Global : NinjectHttpApplication
{
    protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();

        /* various bindings */

        return kernel;
    }

    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AutoMapperConfig.RegisterMappings();
    }
    /* rest of Global.asax methods (Session_Start, Application_BeginRequest, etc.) with empty bodies */
```

RegisterMappings method

```
public static class AutoMapperConfig
{
    public static void RegisterMappings()
    {
        /* multiple calls to Mapper.CreateMap() */

        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    }
}
```

Svc file markup

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#"
            Debug="true"
            Service="MyApp.Services.MyAppService"
            Factory="Ninject.Extensions.Wcf.NinjectServiceHostFactory" %>
```

Everything else works, I've already created a test client (a simple console app) and added a service reference. Service methods get called just fine, it is just that these mappings are a bit problematic since AutoMapper keeps throwing AutoMapperMappingException exceptions ("Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.") for the obvious reasons.
The application's app pool is DefaultAppPool. Should I create a separate one?

I really don't understand the problem here. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, it required some additional searching but I found the answer here - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ninject/wRy3ELSV4bU

The problem was that NinjectHttpApplication class itself implements the Application_Startup method so it is impossible to implement it in your own derived class (Global class).
To simulate such behavior one needs to override the OnApplicationStarted Ninject's method.
This is how it looks like regarding my particular problem:

```
protected override void OnApplicationStarted()
{
    AutoMapperConfig.RegisterMappings();
}
```